# Iwahori-spherical tempered representations with fixed vectors for larger parahoric subgroups

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, p-adic-groups

Let $F$ be a $p$-adic field and $G$ be split over $F$ plus all other usual adjectives. Let $\pi$ be an admissible tempered representation with Iwahori-fixed vectors. Let $P\supset I$ be some parahoric subgroup of $G$. What is known about the circumstances for which $\pi$ has $P$-fixed vectors?

For example, principal series will admit fixed vectors under maximal parahorics, and the Steinberg representation of $G$ doesn't admit any $P$-fixed vectors for $P\supsetneq I$. What goes on in between?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that one can give a necessary criterion (most simply stated for tempered representations) for $P$-fixed vectors in terms of the unipotent part of the parameter and the dimension of the corresponding Springer fibre. I do so in Theorem 19 [here (arXiv)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.07148). Namely, if $w_{P}$ is the longest element in the parahoric subgroup of the affine Weyl group defined by $P$, and $\ell(w_P)>\dim_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathcal{B}_u)$, then $\pi^P=\{0\}$ for any standard module $\pi=K(u,s,\rho)$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the flag variety of $G^\vee$.